# Rider IDE huge usage logo

Tags: c#, rider, jetbrains-rider, toplevel-statement

[image]

Does anyone know if this is a bug or something? I've tried to google it but can't find a solution. And is it impossible to turn off top-level statements in c# rider?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? If it's Linux, which Desktop Environment? Also, are you using the New UI (Settings > Appearance & Behavior > New UI)?

Comment: Mac 12.6.1 Monterey, the thing is when I developed in unity with rider this problem didn't occur. When I open a new solution with just C# itself, it becomes like this. Also, I'm trying to find a way to turn off the top-level statement but doesn't seem to find it in Rider. I know is possible to turn it off in VScode however, turning it off in VS code does not made any impact on Rider

Comment: It looks like an UI bug. My Mac is in my office right now and I can't check it on macOS (Windows here at home). Anyway, try switching to New UI, if you're not yet using it, or switching back to the old one. I have been experiencing weird issues lately on multiple JetBrains tools. It probably has something to do with them refactoring the UI and introducing a new one based on Skia.

Comment: OK, I just switch to the new UI and now it's displayed correctly, thanks for the tips. I just need to set the theme and get used to it